# I deleted the Facebook account connected to my Stack Overflow account. Are there any consequences?

Tags: support, accounts

I deleted the Facebook account connected to this Stack Overflow account. To log in I have always used the Facebook button.

I would really like to know if there are some technical consequences of my Facebook account being deleted regarding this Stack Overflow account. How will I be able to log in from now on if I can't use the Facebook button? As far as I know this account does not have its own password.

Should I just create a new account?

Comment: How did you loged in now?

Comment: My session was still active from the time my facebook account existed, that's why I am too scared to log out before knowing what I should do.

Comment: The following FAQ might be helpful, you are going to need to add a new login method: [How do I add or remove login credentials from my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials)

Comment: I think you can change your password(settings->My Logins) and login with your email that you used for Facebook.

Comment: Thank you very much both.

Comment: Out of interest: if you were worried about this, why didn't you check *before* deleting your Facebook account?

Comment: I actually didn't think about that. This is my only "connected" account. I normally preffer not creating such kind of dependencies, but when I first registered here I was a bit in a hurry so I just clicked on the Facebook button. Now after opening the page I realized that this could end in a problem.

Comment: I've actually locked out my account quiet a few times on different sites due to this. Then I always had to send a mail to support to reset my password. Bad guy login-dev.

Comment: @OferZelig ? I don't see anything bad with his question or do I lack common sense? This question seem to me more as out of curiosity then `you did foolish decision, please spell it out.`.

Comment: If you delete a Facebook account, it's not actually deleted right away. You can re-activate it by just logging again for quite a period of time, so that might be a solution for you in case you have trouble changing your login options on Stack Exchange or any other site. PS, @jonrsharpe I think your question was fine and it crossed my mind as well.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

You can go to your profile page > `Edit Profile and Settings` > `My Logins`.

From here you can `add more logins...`, for example using a google, yahoo, etc account or an `OpenId` if you have one.

See https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials and [How do I change my OpenID provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers) for more information.

Answer (score 25):

You could always undelete your facebook account, it doesnt really delete it, just deactivates it.

This might help someone who has already signed out of facebook.

Comment: Having a Facebook account just for SO seems a bit ... weird to me.

Comment: @YUNOWORK.. but as a means to an end (had his session expired), just to log back in this is a perfectly acceptable (albeit, long winded) solution.

Comment: @YUNOWORK well, if it is just to *regain* login, it seems reasonable. Reactive FB, log into SO using the FB account, [add additional login options](https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials), remove FB login, deactivate FB again.

Comment: You can use your FB account to log into lots of sites, so just for SO seems like overkill, but if you use it for SO and 10 other sites, that seems like a perfectly good usage even if you aren't active on FB itself.

Comment: This is not correct. You can indeed delete your account **completely**. However, you have to wait 14 days first. In this time you can still take back the delete request.

Comment: You can but its not easy and most people never find that option.

Comment: @idmean no, your account will just turn into a shadow profile. It's never deleted.  I "deleted" mine years ago and still get mad spam every day.  Also you will have a shadow profile even if you never created one in the first place.

Comment: @glyph I *really deleted* mine some years ago and I don't get any emails from Facebook, all my public comments have been removed and they do not recognise my email if I try to log in. You can [get help here if you want to delete your account.](https://www.facebook.com/help/224562897555674).

Comment: @idmean I made numerous attempts to be removed from their spam and eventually gave up. I'm caught in some kind of snafu now. Even if they do stop spamming, the shadow profile will persist.  It's a known "issue." Thanks for the link though. Someday I will try again.

Comment: to remove it permanently, just follow this link: https://www.facebook.com/help/delete_account

Answer (score 11):

Just click the "Forgot password" link on the login page and input the email that was tied to FB and SO will send you a reset password email from which you can set a password for logging in directly.

Your email (that SO took from FB) is saved in a database similar to if you were registered using email, so your account can be considered as an account that was registered by usual email confirmation, just that you "do not know your password".

If you perform a password reset (I assume you have access to the email account used to register on Facebook), you will be able to set a new password—and thus be able to login with the email and the newly-set password.

I have tried this and it works; here are the exact steps I did:

1. For a SO account that was created by FB, I opened SO in a browser without an active session
2. Went to login page and chose "forgot password"
3. Typed my email for Facebook and submitted the form
4. I received an email with this content:

   > Someone requested an account recovery on Stack Overflow for
   > example@gmail.com. If you did not request this, just ignore this
   > email. We'll keep your account safe.
   > You can log in to Stack Overflow using the following credentials:
   > Choose the "Log in with Facebook" option (example@gmail.com) If you'd
   > like to use example@gmail.com to log in, click here to set a new
   > password.
5. With this email, I just set up a new password.

Now, I can login with my email and password from the usual login page, without interacting with Facebook. So, at this point, it is similar to having an account where you can login using the email and password directly, without interacting with third parties.

Comment: OAuth/OpenID registrations do not involve passwords. They use tokens. This answer is factually incorrect.

Comment: @akaRash, i think u misunderstood my point, or maybe i wrote it not clear enough, i did not mean tokens I mean the usual passwords that are used when u login somewhere as usual email/password pair.

Comment: @akaRash, my guess was correct, i just tried it, and it works

Comment: @akaRash doesn't he mean that you should use the "forgot password" option, even though you didn't set a password (because you used OAuth/OpenID), it will allow you to set a new one? Sounds possible :p

Comment: @g00glen00b, more than possible - i overcame my laziness and just gave it a try, it worked fine ))))))

Comment: No... OAuth registration is password less, that is the entire point. Client application doesn't deal with passwords, the OAuth provider does. @dav What do you mean by "tried"? What did you do exactly? Steps to repro?

Comment: @akaRash, `OAuth registration is password less` u r correct and I am well aware of that, no one said u should type ur password with OAuth,  the point was because the guy deleted his fb and he could not login with that, this way he would restore/set up his password - the password of SO, the password that people have when they register without OAuth. I wrote the steps taht i did, pls take a look

Comment: This is the real answer that provides the possibility to just use e-mail.

Comment: Why is this not a top answer for this question. It is a completely valid way to address the problem.

Answer (score 3):

To those saying that the facebook account is disabled but not deleted; you might be wrong.

You can permanently delete your account using this link:

https://www.facebook.com/help/delete_account