# I deleted my Facebook account and can't log in anymore

Tags: support, login, accounts

Since I deleted my Facebook account (permanently) I cannot log in with my regular account (lukas.coenig) to Stack Exchange anymore. (The account I'm writing this question with is just temporary and has little reputation.)

I saw the question *[I deleted the Facebook account connected to my Stack Overflow account. Are there any consequences?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295139/i-deleted-the-facebook-account-connected-to-my-stack-overflow-account-are-there)*, but the answers there don't work for me as you have to be logged in to change the login settings, and obviously I'm not...

Have I lost my account forever or is there still hope?

Comment: You could temporarily revive your Facebook account (accounts there are never deleted, just disabled) and add an additional login like a Google/OAuth login. Then remove your Facebook account again.

Comment: SE may be able to merge the accounts -- are they linked to the same email address?

Comment: Since you've also linked that account via Stack Exchange OpenID, you should be able to trigger a password reset via https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery and access the account that way. If you continue to have problems, use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page to reach out to the community team (if Oldskools method doesn't work).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I'll try them and let you know how it turns out. However, @Oldskool: it is possible to delete Facebook accounts permanently, and that's what I did...

Comment: This kind of thing is why I avoid things like Facebook sign-in like the plague. Vendor lock-in is never a nice thing. It's good to keep everything separate, and replaceable at any time.

Comment: Unless that vendor is Stackoverflow, you mean.

Answer (score 35):

Ok, so the suggestion by Matt worked for me, just resetting the account password:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery

Comment: Hey, you're back!

Comment: Yeah, it's great! Thanks for the help...